# Why my css selector gets converted to upper case in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

I have css file as follow

```
/*mycss.css*/
body {
margin: 0px; padding: 0px; 
}
a:link {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: normal; text-decoration: underline;
}
a:visited {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: normal; text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-decoration: none;
}
```

i have correctly linked this in my php file and works fine in `firefox,chrome` but when i open it in `Internet explorer` my css looks like following all my css selectors are converted to upper case

```
 /*mycss.css*/
BODY{
margin: 0px; padding: 0px; 
}
A:link {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: normal; text-decoration: underline;
}
A:visited {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: normal; text-decoration: underline;
}
A:active {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-decoration: none;
}
A:hover {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Is this causing an error with the CSS?  IE just kinda does this.

Comment: You're talking about the IE dev tools.

Comment: Does this result in an error in the display of some kind?  Or are you just asking out of curiosity?

Comment: They get converted to uppercase on the developer tools or in your stylesheet? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Are you viewing the file directly or using an inspection tool? Also which version of IE?

Comment: some pages it does not convert to upper case and for some pages it does so it changes the view of my page is there any way to fix this. thanks.

Comment: @swan it doesn't change functionality. Maybe you're using an other Doctype or your html is uppercase...

Comment: i am using ie9 and viewing css from inspection tool

Comment: i am using this doctype does it effects '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
'

Comment: thanks all my problem get solved...

Comment: I have changed my doctype to this <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> and its get solved that's it.

Answer (score 4):

This is the way IE parses CSS selectors.

It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: but for some pages it does not convert to upper case and for some pages it does why this so...

Comment: I have changed my doctype to this <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> and its get solved that's it.