# What does it mean when IE Developer Tools shows CSS property in caps next to other property?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Sometimes I have noticed that Internet Explorer 8 Developer Tools shows some CSS properties in capital letters next to another property. But usually there is always one property per row, and you can turn them on and off individually with the checkbox. See my screenshot below. In this case, clicking the checkbox turns both properties on and off (so both properties are being recognised). Why does this happen?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I don't know and hope you find the answer but I must say,because I feel that you are contributing to a problem that has to come to end soon.Why are you supporting IE8?The most understandable reason is that you are supporting internal applications on corporate computers that cannot be upgraded.But why is this acceptable? Why are we supporting these archaic browsers,requiring shims and their own css design?On my web applications I show a message to the user saying that we do not support anything less than IE9 and explain that technology moves to fast to do so.

Comment: I work in an educational institution where there are several thousand users all stuck with IE8. There are many other large organisations in the same situation. There's nothing more annoying that seeing messages saying I should upgrade my browser - I know I should, but I can't.

Comment: I understand, and I am sure it is frustrating for you. I just gotta say one other thing though. The costs of upgrading the computers is less than the software development costs over just a few year time frame with almost no consideration for the size of the company if even half the company uses the internal software.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing, Chrome Frame will replace the need to support IE8 and is an easy install of all employees even if Tech Support has to do it.

Comment: I don't find it frustrating developing for all browsers as, only frustrating when I visit websites at work that don't work well with older browsers.

Comment: Well then you are part of the problem with that statement,because, if you fully understood, you probably wouldn't have the gripe in the first place.There are two things you are not fully considering in their actual scale,the costs to support old IE browsers and the impact of that support on development teams. Making sophisticated web apps fast and intuitive is a costly burden as is,now add the burden of support for old versions of IE8,you could staff 3 or 4 people on that problem alone,and it always makes a clean web application ugly and that impacts developers' morale and productivity.

Comment: Here is a great article on the issue: https://hiringsolved.com/blog/onward-why-we-dont-support-internet-explorer-8/

Comment: Not really the place for a discussion on this topic, but as the browser upgrade or install of Chrome Frame within the organisation that I work is not within my control I will continue to develop for all browsers that show up in our statistics in any significant number.

Comment: Not saying that you are in anyway related to this but I had to share with you that you inspired the first blog article on my new company website of all the random things lol: http://www.sandiegosoftware.net/blog/

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10282215/2744839), it appears to just be a quirk of how IE reacts to certain HTML doctypes, and doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: I don't think this is the same issue. The other question is about viewing the entire CSS file and how HTML tags are converted to upper case. My question relates specifically to the fact that sometimes (quite rare) they appear in the same row, but it's only the second property in the row that appears in upper case (property in caps not tag).